# Auth0 on-premise or private server deployment

Tags: deployment, auth0

I am looking for Auth0 deployment in a private servers and I haven't come across any such deployment options so far.
Is Auth0 deployable in private on-premise servers? If yes, please share the link or information on how it can be done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid Auth0 is a cloud-only solution.

Out of curiosity, which use-cases do you intend to tackle with Auth0?